# Manually push data to Google Analytics Goals

Tags: google-analytics

I have create a goal in GA based on destination. But due to some changes that we did, we not using destination anymore and based on ajax result. So I wonder here if I still can track the goals by using it manually.

I found some docs here [Google Annalytics Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide), but did not found anything related to Goals.

Would be great if got experienced people in GA to advice on this

Answer (score 0):

Send to analytics a fictitious pageview (virtual pageview) to activate the goal where you want.

In the measurement protocol you can use the `dp` parameter to define the page path (or *dl* the location URL) and match it to the one that activates the goal in Analytics.